# html dragend event doesn't fire on phone's browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop, mobile-browser

recently I'm making drag event.

Everything works right on computer,

but when I **open webpage on phone**, 
the 'dragend' event dosen't fire,
but others drag event like dragstart, dragover...work normally.
my code is like this

```
list.on('dragstart',function(e){    
    e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('text',e.target.id);
})
.on('dragend',function(){//dosen't fire on phone's browser
    console.log('exit')
    //....
})
.on('dragover',function(e){
    e.preventDefault()  
    //....
}
```

If there's any solution that can make this work on most type of phone?
By the way my phone' system is Android7.0

Here's my exercise webpage(source code is in my repository),if interested you can open on your phone and computer to see the difference.
[Mypage](https://timtnlee.github.io/Todo-List/)

Comment: Already answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20927759/html5-drag-and-drop-for-mobile

Comment: @Nikola Spalevic  thanks a lot!