# touchmove not firing but mousemove does

Tags: javascript, css, touch-event

I got this [code](https://codepen.io/balvin/full/aKrRbG/):

```js
let item1=document.querySelector(".item1");
let item2=document.querySelector(".item2");
let container=document.querySelector(".container");
let posX,posY,startX,startY,move=false;
item1.addEventListener("touchstart",permision1);
item1.addEventListener("mousedown",permision1);
container.addEventListener("touchend",permision2);
container.addEventListener("mouseup",permision2);
item1.addEventListener("touchmove",data);
item1.addEventListener("mousemove",data);
item2.addEventListener("touchmove",changeColor2);
item2.addEventListener("mousemove",changeColor2);
function permision1(e){
  e.preventDefault();e.stopPropagation();
  item1.style.willChange="transform";
  x=e.clientX || e.touches[0].clientX;
  y=e.clientY || e.touches[0].clientY;
  let rect=item1.getBoundingClientRect();
  startX=x-rect.left;
  startY=y-rect.top;
  move=true;
}
function permision2(e){
  e.preventDefault();e.stopPropagation();
  item1.style.willChange="auto";
  move=false;
}
function data(e){
   e.preventDefault();e.stopPropagation();
   if(!move)return
   posX=e.clientX || e.touches[0].clientX;
   posY=e.clientY || e.touches[0].clientY;
   requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
function update(){
  if(move){
  item1.style.transform=`translate3d(${posX-startX}px,${posY-startX}px,0)`;
    requestAnimationFrame(update);}
}
function changeColor2(e){
  e.preventDefault();e.stopPropagation();
  item2.style.backgroundColor="red";
}
```

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;box-sizing:border-box}
.container{
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
}
.item1{
  position:fixed;
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  background-color:blue;
}
.item2{
  position:fixed;
  top:300px;left:0;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:green;
  animation: moving 10s infinite;
}

@keyframes moving {
  0% {
    transform:translateX(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform:translateX(50vw);
  }
  100% {
    transform:translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item1"></div>
  <div class="item2"></div>
</div>
```

The objective of the code is that you should drag the blue box to down the page , when the mouse or the touch is over the green box this green box will be now red, it works with mouse but not with touch in cellphone mode, this is not actually my real code but it gives enough information what the problem is.

Comment: Sorry, I misread and thought you were just trying to get the color to change. It appears that the touchmove event will only fire on an object if the touch start happened on it. Try looking into the drag events. developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp I tried with celphone and does not work

Comment: Can you provide a code example?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop

Comment: See if this helps.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20927759/html5-drag-and-drop-for-mobile

Comment: that was the point, on mobile I can not use drag and drop, and touchmove seems to work only for objects that have touchstart