# Drag and Drop in JS with drag-handle on touch-devices

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to create a drag-and-drop application using vanilla JS.

```
Example:  https://codepen.io/dever52/pen/MWrJxrL
```

However, this only works with a mouse. So i can't drag the element on a touch-device.

I've tried using the ontouchstart and ontouchend event to be able to use it on touch devices, but this doesn't work (see comments in the codepen) as expected.
Is there a way how to make this work for touch devices?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer can help you -> [html5 drag and drop FOR MOBILE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20927759/html5-drag-and-drop-for-mobile)

Most mobile devices do not listen to the drag events that are bound to the DOM. I would recommend using the touchmove event and the events that go along with with it. It would look something like:

I think these event listeners can help you

```
  var el = document.getElementById('drag');

  el.addEventListener("touchstart", handleStart, false);
  el.addEventListener("touchend", handleEnd, false);
  el.addEventListener("touchcancel", handleCancel, false);
  el.addEventListener("touchleave", handleEnd, false);
  el.addEventListener("touchmove", handleMove, false);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the dragging doesn't start if I use the same eventhandler for mousedown and touchstart. How do I have to use handleStart for touch?

Comment: what if we have a list of items. how can we listen to each element's event?